# Bootstrap fixed header with jQuery-One-Page-Nav

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap.

I have added this to my page to make the navbar go with the scroll.
`<div class="nav-collapse collapse **navbar-fixed-top**">`

But I can't seem to get it into place again with css. You can see the the place I want it to be by removing `position:fixed`.

The second problem is, when scrolling the page, the links should be active as to what section I am on. This somehow does not work anymore.

I am using jQuery One Page Nav Plugin and Twitter Bootstrap.

[Link to live site](http://posterlikes.com/page)

Answer (score 2):

By default, Bootstrap removes the fixed position for tablets and phones. If you want to override this, try:

**Edit**

```
@media (max-width: 979px){

    .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    }  

}
```

For your menu links, currently you have:

```
<a href="#section-2">Cv</a>
```

which links to

```
 <div class="full-2">
 <div class="container-narrow">
 <div class="section" id="section-2">
 <section>
 ....
```

Try changing this to:

If this doesn't do the trick, move the section div as below:

```
 <section id="section-2">
 <div class="full-2">
 <div class="container-narrow">

 ....
```

**Update**

The syntax in your @media css isn't quite correct (my mistake earlier), what you want is:

```
/*By default, Bootstrap removes the fixed position for tablets and phones*/
@media (max-width: 979px){

.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
position: fixed;
    }
}
```

Then in your html you need to add an extra class to your navbar to specify that you want it affixed:

```
<div id="top-nav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

Once you have done that everything works well and you will just need to play with the styling of the dropdown nav links.

See this live: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/KbMvX/  and http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/KbMvX/show/

Comment: Thanks i have added your code. The problem is i cant get my menu in the right place. Is it going out of the "container-narrow".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by'... can't get my menu in the right place' As far as I can see, the links from the top menu connect to the correct place in the body of the page. FYI, at the moment section-1 wraps around the entire page, unless there's a reason for this probably better if you close it before opening section-2

Comment: Yes the links works fine. Is is a css positioning question. After i added position:fixed the navigation position got out of the flow. If you remove `.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;}´ you can see how it should look.

Comment: Cant make it work. I have tried adding your code but it does not work for me somehow.

Comment: Are you sure? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/KbMvX/ . It's a simplified version of your page with the update to the @media syntax and addition of the navbar-fixed-top closs to the top-nav div noted above. FYI, you have some validation blips which would probably be good to fix as well: http://bit.ly/XvJE4p   . Hope this helps!

Comment: navbar-fixed-top is not working it has to be affix span12. If you look at your jsfiddle the menu is exspanding fullwidth. I still cant get the nav to look good when resizing the browser. The menu is on top of the mobile menu icon. Also it is not centred. Could you take a look ?

Comment: My live example has solved most of your original concerns. If you want to create a working jsFiddle, then maybe I can do more. That way we are both looking at the same thing

Comment: My layout is totally messed up. Could you take a look at the site and see where the problem is. I will then make a JsFiddle with that. The problem is more when i resize the browser. I have no margin on left side. The menu slides under some stuff. i cant toggel the small responsive nav button. If i could post my hole pages it would be better.